# Adding new methods to classes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, monkeypatching

In Ruby we can add a new method to a previously defined class by dynamically modifying it at runtime:

```
class String
  def to_magic
    "magic"
  end
end
```

Is it possible to do the same in JavaScript? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes, via [`String.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype) and similar. Example: [`.trim()` polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Compatibility). Just note that monkey patching in JavaScript can affect other operations, like `for..in` loops, negatively.

Comment: even though i didnt downvote, probably because if you searched your title in a search engine you would have found quite a few pages on prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent in JavaScript:

```
String.prototype.toMagic = function(){ 
   return "magic"; 
}

console.log("".toMagic());//>>> "magic"
```